# EF4 View is excluded. How can I include it when I have no control over the DB?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ria

I'm consuming a MSSQL DB via EF4 and need to include a view (of employees).  It has an employeeid column, but this column appears to allow nulls (there's only 1 out of 172,000 rows which I am guessing is some kind of placeholder or default value used by the application).  If I select the View when building the model I get this error:

> "The table/view TABLE_NAME does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it".

I have no control over the DB, I am unable to view the definition of the view to determine the underlying tables, the design of the DB is not going to get changed, but I need to include the user data from this view.

Is there a way I can force the model to include it?

Thanks

M

Answer (score 0):

I had specific cases where I made use to what is know as "Materialization"

the whole idea is that you can add the old fashioned ADO stored procedure and makes it called from the object context.

this was you don't need to do any changed on the edmx or the database

this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/adodotnetentityframework/thread/b7630f85-0ef0-4d06-8633-70faa2849583) shows a simple example